# Applying multiple 'for' in one list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to apply multiple 'for' in one list to use previously created lists.

I also need to round the values in the last list to the second digit, but there is a problem that I don't understand.

Here is part of the code:

```
koef_ob_dvig = 39
v_list = [0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120, 140, 160, 170]
n = [i * koef_ob_dvig for i in v_list]
Ne_list = [round((x / 3600 * mekh_kpd) * (G * koef_dor_sopr + k * F * (x ** 2) / 13), 2) for x in v_list]

n_tabl = [0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120]
Ne_tabl = [0, 20, 50, 73, 92, 100, 92]
n_graph = [round((max(n)/100 * x1), 2) for x1 in n_tabl]
Ne_graph = [round((max(Ne_list)/100 * x2), 2) for x2 in Ne_tabl]

#Further problems arise

Mk_tabl = [(30 * x3 / 3.14 for x3 in Ne_graph) / x4 for x4 in n_graph]

# This part works correctly (30 * x3 / 3.14 for x3 in Ne_graph)
# But when I try to divide each received element into the corresponding element of the n_graph list an error occurs
```

Comment: Could you write it with basic for-loop ? then well modify it in list-comprehension. Could you also provide an example, if `Ne_graph = [1, 2, 3]` what does `Mk_tabl` will be ? Because "applying multiple for" means nothing

Comment: Please, **do not** use Markdown syntax in code. It just makes a giant mess of things. Use comments.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what the actual issue is? Expected Output vs Actual Output would help.

Comment: With your parenthesization, you have a list comprehension that generates a list of generator expressions. What, exactly, do you want to divide by `x4`? Each element in the expression? The sum? Something else? Or do you want `[30*x3/3.14/x4 for x3 in Ne_graph for x4 in n_graph]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand clearly what your objective is for this particular piece of code, but I think it's either one of 2 things.

Forgetting about the specific calculations for a second, and assuming that your goal for the **Mk_tab1** variable is to perform calculations on *each* element in **Ne_graph** with *each corresponding* element in **n_graph**: 
 ie, with this example data below:

```
#consider this basic example
#pretend that you wanted to just divide each element of Ne_graph by each element of n_graph:

Ne_graph = [a, b, c, d, e]
n_graph = [1,2,3,4,5]
...
Mk_tab1 = [a,b/2,c/3,d/4,e/5]
```

If that's what you wanted, then the best way to go about that would be to create a function that takes 2 lists of equal length as an input, runs a for loop, and returns a list of the same length with the required calculations; something like this:

```
def myfun(list1,list2):
  if len(list1) != len(list2):
    #throw error, do something else
  else:
    result = [list1[i] / list2[i] for i in range(len(list1))]
    return result

Mk_tab1 = myfun(Ne_graph,n_graph)
```

If what you actually want is to run calculations of *every* element in Ne_graph with *every* element in n_graph: 
 for example:

```
#consider the same basic example
#if you wanted to operate on each element in one list with each element of the other list
#then the result would be a 2D list; meaning you need to list comp twice:

Ne_graph = [a,b,c,d,e]
n_graph = [1,2,3,4,5]
...
Mk_tab1 = [[a,b,c,d,e],
           [a/2,b/2,c/2,d/2,e/2],
           [a/3,b/3,c/3,d/3,e/3],
           [a/4,b/4,c/4,d/4,e/4],
           [a/5,b/5,c/5,d/5,e/5]]
```

Then that could be accomplished something like this:

```
Mk_tab1 = [[x/y for x in Ne_graph] for y in n_graph]
```